# AnnotatedStringBuilder.withStyle cannot call stringResource anymore (jetpack compose 1.2.0)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have been using withStyle extensively to build annotated string. For example to show

> **OPTION A** or **OPTION B**

I do

```kotlin
val optionAorB = buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.h2.toSpanStyle()) { append(stringResource(R.string.option_a)) })
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.body2.toSpanStyle()) { append(stringResource(R.string.or)) })
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.h2.toSpanStyle()) { append(stringResource(R.string.option_b)) })
}
```

This was working like a charm until I updated jetpack compose to `1.2.0`. Now compiler throws error

`@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

One solution can be to get stringResource outside of `withStyle` 's lambda `block`. But I have used this on tons of places so extracting string (and other compose resource) outside of lambda `block` of `withStyle` will just make code more mess.

Any one found a cleaner solution for this?

Comment: Just use the code reported in the question in a Composable function

Comment: It's already in side composable function. I think the problem is lambda block of `withStyle` is not considered composable where string resource is fetched.

Comment: @HBB20 This was presumably fixed in `1.2.0-alpha06` (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219764003) and, assuming it was not reverted, this fix should have made it into `1.2.0` (stable) that was released on July 27, 2022. I also have no problem if I am testing your sample on `1.1.1` and on `1.2.0` (stable) inside a `@Composable` of course. It works on both. Is the code sample you posted your actual code, because I see an extra `)` at the end of each line (I have to remove those for the sample to even compile).

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by @Ma3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73282496/annotatedstringbuilder-withstyle-cannot-call-stringresource-anymore-jetpack-com#comment129428697_73282496), this is probably already fixed. If you're like me and using a version that doesn't have the fix yet, the link they supplied also [contains a workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219764003#comment2):

```
val optionAorB = buildAnnotatedString {
    val optionA = stringResource(R.string.option_a)
    val orStr = stringResource(R.string.or)
    val optionB = stringResource(R.string.option_b)
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.h2.toSpanStyle()) { append(optionA) })
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.body2.toSpanStyle()) { append(orStr) })
    withStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.h2.toSpanStyle()) { append(optionB) })
}
```